# Manipulate Time Stamp

Tags: r, datetime

Given the following time stamp

```
timeind <- c("Q1/2005", "Q2/2005", ... "Q4/2012")
```

I expect that the return would be as follows:

1st column represent time in quarter

2nd column represent time in year

How do I manipulate the data to obtain the result ?

Thank you

Comment: read.table(text=timeind,sep="/",header=F) would work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure about your expected result.

```
  timeind <- c("Q1/2005", "Q2/2005", "Q4/2012")

 library(zoo)
 as.yearqtr(timeind, "Q%q/%Y")
 #[1] "2005 Q1" "2005 Q2" "2012 Q4"
```

#### Update.

Based on the new info.

```
 read.table(text=timeind,sep="/",header=F,stringsAsFactors=F)
#  V1   V2
#1 Q1 2005
#2 Q2 2005
#3 Q4 2012
```